# Do select cases in VB6 automatically cascade?

Tags: vb6

I come from a C/Java background where switch cases have a cascading effect unless you put a break statement

```
  switch(index)
   {
       case 0: doSomething();        
       case 1: doSomethingElse(); 
       // ...
   }
```

So case 0 cascades to case 1.

Is this the case with VB? Will case 0 cascade to case 1 automatically as above?

```
  Select Case Index

  Case 0 ' code
  Case 1 ' code
  ...
  End Select
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the Select/Case in VB6 does not have a "break" statement.  In fact, I don't think that "break" is even a reserved word in VB6.

If code in case 0 runs, then it will not cascade to case 1.

Comment: Glad I could help!  I'm just surprised to see that people still use VB6.

Comment: No, I am not! I am just trying to understand what the code is doing, so that I can replicate the same logic in Java.

Comment: +1. Just like the [manual says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266274(v=vs.60).aspx). Quote: If *testexpression* matches any `Case` expressionlist expression, the statements following that `Case` clause are executed up to the next `Case` clause, or, for the last clause, up to `End Select`